# textarea fields are not displaying &nbsp; while saving page

Tags: html, jsp, parsing, textarea

i have a jsp page with textarea fields. I am entering `&nbsp;` in the fields, after updating the form those values are disappearing when i open it again. How can i get previously entered value in the jsp textarea field.

For this do we need any parsing mechanism or any String replaceAll function?

Comment: Please post the problematic code.

Answer (score 5):

If you have any HTML entity in the textarea, it will simply be replaced with the character it represents.

```
 <textarea name='txt1'>Test&nbsp;one</textarea>
```

That nbsp would be replaced by a space.

So you must replace the ampersand by the HTML entity for ampersand if you want the literal HTML representation of the HTML entity to appear in the text box:

```
 <textarea name='txt1'>Test&amp;nbsp;one</textarea>
```

Comment: can i use this logic or do you have any other logic in java `if(elementStr.indexOf("&") != -1)
 elementStr = elementStr.replaceAll("&[^a][^m][^p][^;]", "&amp;");`

Comment: i just added like `elementStr = elementStr.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");`